# helpオプションを"optional arguments"グループから、別のグループに変更したいです。

Tags: python

## 環境

- Python 3.7.2

## 背景

[argparser](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html) でCLIコマンドを作成しています。

作成したいコマンドには、以下のオプション引数があります。

- `--project_id`
- `--user_id`
- `--organization_id`
- `--logdir`
- `--yes`

`--logdir`と`--yes`オプション引数は、全コマンドで共通のオプション引数です。
ヘルプ表示では、これらのオプションを"positional arguments"や"optional arguments"と区別して表示したいです。[add_argument_group](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#argument-groups) を使って、`--logdir`と`--yes`オプション引数は"global optional arguments"という引数グループにしました。

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--project_id', type=str, help='Project ID')
    parser.add_argument('--user_id', type=str, help='User ID')
    parser.add_argument('--organization_id', type=str, help='Organization ID')

    # 共通のオプション引数
    group = parser.add_argument_group("global optional arguments")
    group.add_argument('--yes', action="store_true", help="処理中に現れる問い合わせに対して、常に'yes'と回答します。")
    group.add_argument('--logdir', type=str, default=".log", help="ログファイルを保存するディレクトリを指定します。")

    args = parser.parse_args()
```

```
$ python test_command.py -h
usage: test_command.py [-h] [--project_id PROJECT_ID] [--user_id USER_ID]
                       [--organization_id ORGANIZATION_ID] [--yes]
                       [--logdir LOGDIR]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --project_id PROJECT_ID
                        Project ID
  --user_id USER_ID     User ID
  --organization_id ORGANIZATION_ID
                        Organization ID

global optional arguments:
  --yes                 処理中に現れる問い合わせに対して、常に'yes'と回答します。
  --logdir LOGDIR       ログファイルを保存するディレクトリを指定します。
```

## 質問

`--help`オプションは"optional arguments"グループに所属しています。
しかし`--help`は全コマンド共通なので、"global optional arguments"グループ所属させたいです。
`--help`オプションのグループを変更することは可能でしょうか？
可能でしたら、その方法を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

正攻法とは言えないですが、
以下のようにすると一応移動しました。

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--project_id', type=str, help='Project ID')
parser.add_argument('--user_id', type=str, help='User ID')
parser.add_argument('--organization_id', type=str, help='Organization ID')

# 共通のオプション引数
group = parser.add_argument_group("global optional arguments")
group.add_argument('--yes', action="store_true", help="処理中に現れる問い合わせに対して、常に'yes'と回答します。")
group.add_argument('--logdir', type=str, default=".log", help="ログファイルを保存するディレクトリを指定します。")

### 強引に移動させる
help_action = parser._optionals._group_actions[0]  # optional グループの 0番目が help なので取り出す
parser._optionals._group_actions = parser._optionals._group_actions[1:]  # 0番目を削除
parser._action_groups[2]._group_actions.insert(0, help_action)  # global group の 先頭にhelpを追加
### 

args = parser.parse_args()
```

↓

```
usage: sample.py [-h] [--project_id PROJECT_ID] [--user_id USER_ID]
                 [--organization_id ORGANIZATION_ID] [--yes] [--logdir LOGDIR]

optional arguments:
  --project_id PROJECT_ID
                        Project ID
  --user_id USER_ID     User ID
  --organization_id ORGANIZATION_ID
                        Organization ID

global optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --yes                 処理中に現れる問い合わせに対して、常に'yes'と回答します。
  --logdir LOGDIR       ログファイルを保存するディレクトリを指定します。
```